# Mod inbox notifications sometimes show as orange for meta posts

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, top-bar

With the new(-ish) top bar, moderators receive notifications of questions posted on their child meta and, since fairly recently, notifications of mod newsletter announcements. These were originally both colored blue, but the mod newsletter notification was recently changed to orange. However, since then I (and another mod) have seen the orange diamond for an ordinary meta post as well, but those are still supposed to be blue.

Comment: Because there are no [screenshots with hand-drawn circles in them](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9fj.png), I don't believe you.

Comment: (Also just a note that if there happen to be *both* a mod newsletter announcement and a new meta post you haven't seen, the diamond will be orange. Because orange trumps blue.)